# fitting a monotonic function?

Tags: function-construction, fitting

Let's say I have a few points and derivatives given for a function and I'd like to find the best fit through the data, which is **monotonic**. For example, if I take a polynomial ansatz, I get

```
f[x_] = Sum[a[i] x^i, {i, 0, 4}];
constraints = f[x1] == y1 && f'[x1] == 0 && f[x2] == 0 && f[x3] == y3 && f'[x3] == 0;
result = f[x] /. Solve[constraints, Table[a[i], {i, 0, 4}]][[1]] // FullSimplify;
```

which for some `xi` and `yi` sometimes leads to an interpolation that is not monotonic:

[image]

as can be seen by the fact that the minimum is not at the region boundary.

How can I produce a fit (with the simplest model possible) that would satisfy all constraints and simultaneously return a result that is monotonic?

EDIT:

More details on the data:

The data is always given in terms of points at the far left and far right boundary of a range (positive on the left and negative on the right), slopes at these points are zero, and the position at which the function crosses the x-axis is also known, so it looks something like:

[image]

Example values might be:

```
Xleft=0;
Xright=1;
Xmid=0.41;
```

As a list of points:

```
fvalues={{0,1180},{0.41,0},{1,-570}};
fprimes={{0,0},{1,0}};
```

for which fourth degree polynomial fit produces the non-monotonic function plotted above. Basically, I'm wondering what would be the simplest function template to fit 3 given points and 2 given slopes to, such that the function is monotonic?

Comment: Do you have data with measurement error?  Do you only need the fit to be monotonic in a specific range?  I think you need to give more details.

Comment: @JimB I've added an edit to the question with some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible approach:

```
(* build the function to fit *)
n = 4;
pol[x_] = Sum[a[i] x^i, {i, 0, n}]
(* a[0] + x a[1] + x^2 a[2] + x^3 a[3] + x^4 a[4] *)

fit = NonlinearModelFit[
  Join[ (* the data - y=0 are values, y=1 are derivatives*)
   Prepend[0] /@ fvalues,
   Prepend[1] /@ fprimes
   ],
  {
   (* the model, which is pol[x] for y=0, and pol'[x] for y=1*)
   (1 - y) pol[x] + y pol'[x],
   (* the monotonicity constraint *)
   Reduce[ForAll[x, Xleft <= x <= Xright, pol'[x] <= 0]]
   },
  Table[a[i], {i, 0, n}],
  {y, x},
  Weights -> Join[ (* weights for values and derivatives *)
    Table[10, Length@fvalues],
    Table[1, Length@fprimes]
    ]
  ]

Plot[
  fit[0, x],
  {x, Xleft, Xright},
  Epilog -> {Red, Point@fvalues}
 ]
```

[image]

The idea is to construct a function with an additional parameter (`y`) which controls whether the model returns `pol[x]` or `pol'[x]`. This allows us to specify both function values and derivative values for the fit (since the scales of the two values are off, we need to specify some appropriate `Weights`). The biggest issue of this approach is that `Reduce` takes a while to simplify the constraint, especially for higher order polynomials. Additionally, the constraint will produce complex numbers for some inputs (due to the roots involved), which causes `NonlinearModelFit` to complain.

Comment: Wow, this is interesting! I did not know `NonlinearModelFit` could take `<=` constraints on whole ranges of variable values.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that you have a strong belief that only 3 points, two zero slopes, and monotonicity will faithfully represent all of the values between.  If you don't really know the form of the underlying function, don't want to use more the 3 points, and are using polynomials to approximate the function, then I think you're way optimistic.

I would start with a monotonic function right from the start and not have to worry about determining what relationships the coefficients of a polynomial must have.  One such class of monotonic functions is a cumulative distribution function.  Below I've used a linear function of a Beta distribution:

```
fvalues = {{0, 1180}, {0.91, 0}, {1, -570}};
{{xLeft, yLeft}, {xMid, yMid}, {xRight, yRight}} = fvalues;
```

Given that there are only 3 points there are an infinite combination of α and β values that will provide a monotonic function passing through the 3 points with slopes of zero at each end.  If the midpoint is less than half way, then we set α to some value and solve for β.  Otherwise we set β to some value and solve for α.

```
If[xMid < (xLeft + xRight)/2, α = 3; β =., α =.; β = 3];
sol = NSolve[yRight + 
  (yLeft - yRight)*(1 - CDF[BetaDistribution[α, β], (xMid - xLeft)/(xRight - xLeft)]) == 0, 
   If[xMid < (xLeft + xRight)/2, β, α]][[1, 1]]
(* β -> 5.67779 *)

(* Show the resulting function *)
Show[ListPlot[fvalues, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}], 
  Plot[yRight + 
   (yLeft - yRight)*(1 - CDF[BetaDistribution[α, β] /. sol, 
   (x - xLeft)/(xRight - xLeft)]), {x, xLeft, xRight}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: Plot of data and fit]

Comment: You are right, there are a lot of different monotonic functions around so one really can't get around modeling the problem a bit more. I've looked more into it and turns out the model predicts the function to be given by `Erf` with points and slopes appropriately fitted.

Comment: But doesn't the slope only equal zero at $-\infty$ and $\infty$ when using `Erf`?  You describe a bounded range of values.  One can use the logit-normal distribution function (which is bounded by zero or one but can be modified to any finite range).

Comment: Right again! Slopes equal zero was a simplification for the question here on MA stackexchange, since I did not want to complicate it more than necessary.